# Network drive connects multiple times

Tags: windows-8.1, network-drive

I have a PC with win 8.1 and have 2 network drives that are suposed to autoreconnect on startup.

For some reason one of them reconnects multiple times. I have bound it to Y: but every few days it reconnects as Y: and as T: or L: or whatever free letter. The result is that i have 2 or more connections to the same network location.

i tried to remove it by disconnecting the drive, but it randomly reappears.

then i tried this: `net use /persistent:no`

but all without result.

Thanks!

---EDIT
On computer i clicked "connect network drive" specified the path and selected "automatically connect at startup". and now i have this problem.
A few weeks ago i had this script running on login. But dont use it anymore.

```
Dim objNet, shell, strUserName, UserObj, objDomain, DomainString, UserString
set objNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
on error resume next


objNet.MapNetworkDrive "U:", "\\sbs01\UserShares",True
objNet.MapNetworkDrive "Y:", "\\sbs01\Daten_Neu",True

WSCript.Quit
```

Comment: How is this network drive attached to the network?

Comment: it is a folder on the server. On computer i clicked "connect network drive" specified the path and selected "automatically connect at startup". and now i have this problem.

Comment: How are you connecting on start up? Via a script? Or just using Windows built in 'connect at start up' ? If a script, please edit your post and share it

Comment: sorry for the late reply, was out of office! its reconnecting via the Windows built in connect at startup! a few weeks ago i had a script that did the connect thing but it is not being used anymore and they still keep appearing. will share the script anyway.

Comment: Please edit your question and include this information, it's important and hopefully will help others who read this question understand it better

Comment: Updated! do you have a clue why \\sbs01\Daten_Neu keeps reconnecting multiple times?